# What's Jonas trying to hint to me?

Tags: cipher, music

(The length of the post is due to the size of the hints. Sorry. If you're just skimming through, the quoteblocks and codeblocks are the hints.)

My buddy Jonas has been hinting me about something for the past few days.

I don't know him very well, so I don't know what it could be.

He's been dropping these strange hints.

The first one was an e-mail:

> Yo
>
> qC KoiS (q0 ayYc)
>   O U1gF (o uWqV)

What? That looks really weird. and it's not ROT13 or anything.

Next he sent me this:

```
Heybro
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```

I put it in a code tag since it's REALLY long.

I told him I still didn't get it, then he showed me this:

```
Really bro?

XFdKXEQ4XFFRXEMwXDAwEEtXV1dcMDABAQFcMDBMXDAwSFwwMFwwMFxRUVxERlwwMFxVUktsaWQg
dHEgbmZmdiBnbHpkY21wIGZ2cGFlcGIgdWYgbWZ5ciBvcHlzIEZmemtpeWxqIFFmZ2tpciBlc3lv
IHBjbCB4aHR5aS4KTWZjYm1uciBxbXMga3Z6dyBpeGxlZiBud2NwIG56ZSBmZmNkIHBzdS4KTWZy
IG5ybXNpIHRzcHBmJ2ogY2VpIHRzbHIgZHJiLgpaeCdzIG1wY28gemIgd3ZveWUgbWcgcGNsIHho
dGQgdWlmenYgeGl4cC4KWW91IG1meSd2cCBkcmpjeiBkbXNkcGIgamsuClxUV1xIQlwwME5cMDAv
ICMpIx0vKSYpNTIvOFJ0TVhPUktcOTBneEZ0XEJTXDk2XFAzXFMwXEU4XDk2XEE1XEwyXE1BXEU0
XFdUXFY1XEZDXE44XFFEy6JcQjVcVlBcV0pcRVBcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcUzZcUzJcV0pc
RlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcV1RcV0pcRE1cMDBOATI1NUU+SFw4UlpDXDhFXEZRwqVcTjJc
REdcV1RcV0pcRlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcV1RcV0pcRlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdc
V1RcV0pcRlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcV1RcV0pcRlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcV1Rc
V0pcRlFcUURcR1dcVFdcSkZcUVFcREdcV1RcV0pcRlFcUURcR1dcUTJcMDARCAFcOVYBaAMBEVww
MAIRAQMRAVxGUVxONFwwMBhcMDABAQEBAVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMAECAwRcREdcVDRcMDAYAQEBAQEBXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwAQIDBFxUV1xIQVwwMAwDAVwwMAIQAxBcMDBcMDABXFE1XDgwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwIVxQNzgUXEIwPSdAXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwIVxEMFxXM1w5UgpcXFI2XDlITlxOMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFwwMG9cRDIaGVxDUlxTNGRcOUlcOTNcQTlcTzhcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAMHm3DllxENTM3J0dcVFNcVjVcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAZPFxHNVxDTGTVkDrGnlw5Mlw4MFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAxcOUNgXkFcOTBCXFIyRD1JXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDg3I1xDUHdcWkRcUzVcODJcUTVcVjkaXDlJXEEyXDgwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwTlxONlBcRjZcVFNtXEUwXEJPI1pHQFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAJcMDBAUQpcMDAwcEEOUUwF3Jt6XDhMXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
IQwcXE5BGSApT1w4Ns2aKVxUOFxTMGIpzoEWXEo0XDk3U1xPMkFcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBB
BxNcOTEKaVxSMFxPNAZZDlw4N2dcOTlcODNZWWcSXEJCXlxTOVxSOdygXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
IVw5M1w4McSmXFRFElhcTDJcMDBFXFo2Ulw5MyZFXFEzFzlcUjBDNVxEMjRcUTRcOTRcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDAhXE5BXEczEFxVOVdcUkdcQ09wcVwwMBJcQjhcODEtXDlSXFA51ZQialxIMkFcOU1m
JVxDOGtxXDhPXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDg3E1xUR2xcTzE1XDk5XE1BESs6TlBSARZCGlxHQzUt
XE42XE9BXEc2XFRRElw4UlFuXT0lXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAhxcOFEp0Kk6bVxcWTZcQlY2XDk0XDAw
XDAwXE8wAmI5XEg2IVxBUT9bXDlMM2sGXENSdWxcSThcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDACHFxDUSlcTTJcWTZh
ak1o0Z1cMDAFXDAwXDAwXDAwIFw5SFxFMzZ2XDg3Vlw4QmfamlxSN1dcVTBcSUNBXDAwXDAwXDAw
AVw5M1xONmZcQjlcOVZcUFRcRzVcRTdcTzEoXDAwQVwwMFwwMFwwMAFcOUJkOlxUUlxWMVxINlxF
NlxPMtOkHlw5M0BcMDBcMDBcMDAQ85yNmVxQOVxBOWZcVjXUoAoBJVw4UApbXDlSXDAwXDAwGVxI
NjNcQU5cUFpcRFdcUjZEWFxCTV1ZXEE3UVwwMFwwMFwwMA54XDk0XFI5N1w4OVxSR159E0AKQzNp
XDlMXDhZXDAwGmhuOlxQOVwwMAFcOVVcSTMyXh1oXE03XTNcTTNcWjlAXDAwXDAwCHpDXDlPQ1xK
NVxFNFxOUFxDRjZcMDBcUjBcUzc6c29JXExNXDhCIFw4Q1w5NVxUUVxVNF5cSEFcUDVBXDAwIM+m
Ly1ee1w5NlxDR3BcUjVxClwwMFwwMAIcDgdGb1w5TlxPNm0uXEI1Alw4MFpTXFMwXDAwXDAwzLpc
RjBcMDBcMDBcOUFcTlAuc1xGN1xWUC3eplxTNT0FXDAwXDAwAVw4M1xHOGxcTTlYXEQzzbc7XDAw
UVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMDlcVzRcUzVweFxENz1eXDky16RcTDBcMDABDzlcTkFcRTRr
XFMxb1xKQjhefVUFXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwclZcRFRjXDhXT1xBM2RcTTlcQjBc
MDBcMDA5XDlGVFxPMXBcSUFRfTwvPlxMMhRcWTBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAgdFw5OS8u
XDlSXE83WlxIMFxFTkFcMDAhXEM2MllcU1FcUzRcSEUxXE9NFx0gKUAhXDgzXFkwXDAwXDAwAVxE
VFxTOFwwMFwwMAM4M1xSRiVcRU0ta0hcMDAEPFxCMFxTUVxTNXZcRTdcT00t4Z2BXFkwAVxEVFxT
MHFRXDAwXDAwBzNcODFcRTg2XDAwXDAwGFxON1dcRDRcRTU6dFw5M0dcUzlcRjJcODAMXDlFQ1w5
TVxDMXpiXE82cWtbXEU0zoBcTzBcMDBcUDRvPQZcRDBcMDADXDkxXFQ0XFNWeFwwMFwwMA5ZXFBM
3bpcWkNcVjNcUVJcSUY4O1w5T1w4TAFcQThcRzNcOVJcOFJcVzFcRkM6ZhpcOTh1NVw5WVEBXDkz
XFRTcU5cMDBcMDAZPOekoFwwMElxejtcWjZcRlZcT1VcSDceWlxQOVw5MD0mXDgwPFxQNzN2OVxG
U1w4N15cUDZEXEhGPFxOUUNdXEY2XDgwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwIlAzXE85XDlVXEc0XEM2
XFE1XExCXEY5WRtcOVFcVzUxXEg4XEU4QWpcOEFcOUJcVjV0Zg5cRkR1ZVxaRno3M1xSMAt2TVZc
Tk1gXDAwXDAwXDAwXDkyXDg5XDlaIitZXFxUUWwTXEU2XEVQXFA4CFxCMztcRFcsXDlTXDgzXFIx
UzFcOTNcXEFOXE5CXEYz16RcUzdcTzRcVzPKmFxJOUAiNQJqXDgwU0HViXpLXENcU1ZcRzBcXEI1
GFxQOVw5TWRcRzVcUlJcVTApd1w4RFltXDlDXDkzSFw5VFxRMXBaby5cOU8zXEw2XFk3O1xCVkdc
OVduCC5vWTJ1cVxGVCoCXDkyTlw4UgZcSjlcRE9kXDlBXENVBApzdB0xXEVELdaNQVw4MXdcQjZ6
2Z9SXFIwXFYydi86w5dOXDk51oxcUFBcRDlcQjc+XFYwEXNcVkZcQzJyZFw5RGJHU1xSORRYK1xB
NyQx0KR2Clw5OVxQWlw5RVxWUFFcRTJJeFw5MltGcVw4RUV+XDkzXE8xXDgzXFRJXBxcRVB4XEM1
XEUzYmFcVjdjXDhBCFxNMlxRNVxDMyVcOURcU1DQgFxSNFw4RSoV04s6Z2J1N1xBRkRcUzZcVzQo
XEY1d0BTNTnZnlxQN3oedCVcVjNmXFM41rNcRUItXE0yXFxQNlw4NBdcWjcgE1w5R1xSMlxROAFa
FVpCXE1MXEQwdFxWUC5cOTF1XDlGXENQXQpGaVclXDk5XDk3SxZwXFRHdD0lMGrLlmpcQ0JNNVxP
VOqUlzJcRzlR141cTTM8XE1aXEU5WQFSXFJGIHVcUDNcOTlcT0Q2XEUwGTJNblxVSC1cQjlcOTgL
ZVxNMSBcWkTzp7CkOVw5VFRQxrNcRUJcOU95IUZcOEMlXFU3K1xPVFB1ckUgXDhaU1t1XDhQOlxW
MjpIXEI2XFE03rFcOVBQZ86JXFNQXFIy1JEKRiRcRDRcTk9NalIOdREZXFY3XEU5WFxPUFxDMFMU
XDg0XFIyEFwwMFxPORREXEc5YVJYaFw5MlxGNlxVUlxUOXdcODhleEIQXDg5BlxZNjR7CgEOaBFc
ODZqXE8ydH0zQAhUQlw4MBQoXE4yXFAyLVxBRVxWUFw5OSpmUVxcRTdNM3hcWUMQXDg5BVw5OSdc
UjBcVDRcMDABDgYgXFRKSRFcTlF4XERWXFQ0LVxSMiIkCgJcSEFcMDBcOU85ZFxCRmNcUDISXFMx
36gCTFxBNFw4NCBcOUxcOU09XDg1XDAwXDAwYlxHM1w5Mic9JM6vPlw5UwFJUyIiFXFcOTZcQTRn
XFAzXDhCXEY1XDhVWlxVMBlcSUJcTzJ1XEE0TVxSUlIFXDk5Jlw4SllcTTBcMDBcMDAcXE5DAhhc
QzI4XFc0XFJULVxGMQVQXDAwXE8ydVxBOGxcOTZxXFQzXFNHXEY1JUBcTTUx26xcTEHMklw5NCAr
Oj1cODZcODBcMDBcMDABXDgzXDg5XDkxGVw5QlxWNVxPVUxQAlxMOBtcOTJcUTVcQjM5358DFlw5
Mlw5OVxDNWVu7ISSR1w5MFxGMlRcUTVcOU9AXDAwXDAwXDAwBDBxMEZcVDNMXDk2XDAwBUzeq29c
Q00bXFAzXDk5Tlw4NFxDNlxSNjpoXMWhCCFcUjlcOUge0oBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAhXDgzXDg5AVw5
NlxCMlxNMC1YJFxDQ1xVNhczXn5EXDgwTj5cOUVbElw5NCBcODVcOTBcOURcTlFOXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwAQxcOURcVFEQXDAwDFxWSlxBNi5cTE9eT1w4RBZlXFM2XFRIJVw5M1w5RFxPOSoIJFxM
OU1qXFMwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAQFcOTBkMkRzGlxEUDNcOE9dASRcQzkwXDkwRApcUjkl
UEpcSDR2XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAQ85XDkzPTpcTTNcOTFcOTJUYlxDNFw5M2Bc
VjZvXFI4XEZBb1w5TT1FQFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMHM4XDkwAlwwMAoeXDgz
J1w5NFw4NAdUXFI4R1wwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAh3OVw5RA5cODZMXEwwTkRc
OTlcVDBcUTlcVTBcSjQaXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXEZRXE40XDAwIhBcMDABAwQDAQEBAVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAFc
MDACERAgMDESQE4hQgNgXFdUXFVFXDAwCAEBXDAwAQUCXEVRXE05XEFDXFY5XEgoRFxKMVxEUEdc
Q0MUeFw4UUhcSkF4clw4QXBlXFRUV0FsTn4pX1xZOFxHOUUobVw4VlxKQXg9XE85UVw4MVxEU1xU
N1xTRitcOTLmua5rXDkxXFw4TOS5rnZcOTJcOVlcQzkELhtcVk8XIlxXNVxHOUFcRVsKFCkhB1xM
MFxDNPKFoo1cRVdWXDk056+laFxHQgoX04B6XEwyXFw4WlxCNVhcOTRcUzctXFIwI1xFMz1cOTc5
b1xNNChcT0JcRjZoWz1WXFQwXEhDXE41OFxOOVxDRwxcUlQodlw5NSpkClxDOFxQMlxNNm9zSmhc
UjlcRkNcTzgo3I9jGFw5QklHXE8yXDkwXFM4XEkzFjd4XDlQQVxDQlcDdlxVSRJcQjZze1xQMxNc
QUIdXFYzeWc4XEVEXDlQXFE4XFkwXEIzZz7Di1w5Ni5NV1xJRjtcTjhcUUImXEZSXFQ3ejdBXDlE
XE84ClxONX7QnE1cQjNse1xUNFw5OVxSRlxDUFxQOClcRDQmXDlDXFw4NUEYVlw5MRhGXEgxCHwX
TVw4MlxOMW5cQzgRXEIwXFZSQTdcOEU0XEQ4XFFMBGYtXDk1KlVcVjZcOTU4XFE1NFw5Um5cRU5c
UTJcWTVOXDkyXFI1WFw5VFxKM1FcUTEKOsigXFExW1xZNFxGUn4jXFBXEFVcOUFRXDgzXE43FGNd
ZW8GXFM2XFZJXDg0VFxPMFxROFxZM3ZnXFAwXFc05qKHL+2FtShcSUJcTDgsNFw5Ti3drhZcQTdL
Oh9cVFFeXFYxR1NvbwpcQzg0SlxTUVw4U1JwKTlcODBcOTRcTzEYU1w5WghcRDYqKGo0VwIxXDkx
KFw4OFxSOVxKQlw4OHVcODEcXFBBbXctXHlcVDVLZVxNTVxDOBZcQjhcUlEuK1w4Ulw4NVxHNUda
XFE5XDhDXDlHFVxUNVNcVDZcSjhRXDg0fUBAXFBNQFxadgpcOTJcUjcjGx1cTzdlXEc4UFxMMlxM
QhJcIlxGMFxVMkdbHVxTNwwhXEU1ASBcQzJQXDhOEntcWTVcQlNcODlPXFM0XEkyFxFzXDk5K1w4
MVxVH1xOQgEfXEY5P1xXVFxUNFwwMCMRXDAwAQMFAVwwMAMBAQFcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAB
XDAwAhEQEiAwMUADIVRgcFw4MFxRUVxCQlwwMAgBAwEBPwFcV1RcMDBcOFRTXEU0XDhRXFA3XDhE
XEcxEhVcVE9cVjV2XEI5XFxMNHE9XFo3K1xDNVxcUjdXXFczFylcRTQrVAxcTDFbSlFcOTlcRzJc
OTNAXFU1Gwt5M1xWRSZoG1xQMCJcODBcUVkgXDk0BFxCMCNcVDRTGnxcVDRcR0RcMDBcTzEFS1Nc
QlLTpFw4TwM1PhcaARnaoygIXFM3MhAxXEk1aM20XDkwXExQUFVcOTVoS0tcSThpXEw5XE9DXEZV
IMKTXE8yXFYzXEUwXEQwQVxQRHhKfWFcVzEPV1w5M3tDXE00J2IPV05cVzA/XDg5XFBWXEcxXEI4
QlxRQU5cVzYBVlhgIO2Qm1xJQxU7AjQjXE8zCjdcOEwUXEQyQkQyEVxUM1lGNDhpFCtcUDRXXEM2
EBQrVWJcODUFU1wTKDJuNnxcOEZcRTPEmEhcODQdNVxRWVxENhQFARMKXFc0KlxTViZUZEtZXFkw
alxXMg9cTzRcVElcRTJcUFBPXDlFXFU2XFQ0MH8TNREaBQ9cVUUfRxdjXDhPXENGXFM3XFQ1Mwdc
UjYhXEU1XERMUB5cQjlcRDRcVzJcOFJcVklcQjdcUTUzXDk4PTB9dXRcOTlcRzI7XFI5XFBUXEcw
XEI2VRjKnBw1DFxOQgc1O1xCOGoCSFxSMVw5MFxIQdyhOVxNUWZcODRcRFZ4LFxXRlxBOFxZXFBC
G1w4RHNpDlxWNkBASSFGMVRETAQ6XEJVXDlTXFJJcwFcUDNcOU/Qi1IhXDg1XEQ1DAZYZFxSRyhR
XEw4XFFaXDg2ElxCN1VcUzgcXFI0XEU5XEZQDB1hXDhDZFJcVDFcODMKawofxblcXEU0KQpCXE1M
XFoxXEc5ZDUhT0dcRURcTDRcUUMrKEYlRAp1XFcwXEhCXE40XFxMRFgpSVxPNxFUXEo4E1xGUD9c
UURcRDRcMDAkEVwwMAEDBANcMDADAQEBXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAVwwMAIRECAxQBIwRwMh
T0hgdFxGUVxPWVwwMAgBAgEBPwFcR1dcMDAfXFE4cGhcQzI/dFxMM1xEN1xEVXdcV0dcRjJcOU9c
OE0bXDhEKiJcQlXHlVw5T1xTN1xHOXVcOE/HklhcOEJcRzIdXDhTW1xTNDseBBVcVDV1XFcVXE41
UFxDRlxTNHF0XDhFXDhFXEw4QlxCMlxFVWAURk4lN05cRTVJQVw4QlxEVVxSNQJcODRcUjlcSUMG
XExQEW7GoBFDawFcTzNcOVMWCkAhElw4OVw5SCBoWxUfS2BnTVE0Iio0UShaXFZGAlw4OFw5REgd
XDk3XDhR2ox1XEM3eSNcVDdNXEkzXEI5zoVcUTFcUDJRXEM2XFVTKDFcVUVMLFxMMCAjXE00E1xE
MUdcVzZcUDk3KFxWSFw4NFxGM0xcOVBcQTJiElxTUzxcUjdyOFxGT1xPNBlcQ0NoXE83xp1cUzjQ
gAhcRjQmXEY1XDlOXEwwEDxRXEM3BVduXDhVXDAwSUoHcUVcWTBcODIoaFxSOVxTOEdcRTZcODlF
CmNYXDgyXEEzXEUwXFc0KEcTXFJHXDk1KlRcUTXKlSZcTDBcWTdVUW4dXDlSCjU6XEk4UUpEYlxC
OSpHElxQOFxVODJcOUhAXDg3a1xNM1RcWTdcRlJp562oXFU43KdsOlw4RFxMOVxONeetqVxCNjU5
Dlw5M3RcVk86RkJcQzJmXDhPRFxEMWhcUFcUXDk0NFxHMjlQXEwyXDgzXExBXEVWUlxVNF4oZFw4
Mlw4QcahE1FcT1oKEFxCMVxWTxULCFxVMFxJORE0GVxFOVw4NQotXDg0LB9MDFxMOFBcOEZcOVNc
ODdcU1VrS1w5MuS5rkNcTTFcWUNcOFJcOE/ChR1WF3JcQjZcTjlEfFJcOUNcOVNcOFJpOwUhOFxI
MFoxXE0xCAhcUFlcOTMwXEIxOlw4MlxVMDxUD1xVRTsXXDgxXEUzOH1cBGlcTEJDXDhWdVxXMXUr
XDg5QVw5UVxPNRBcWTdcRDVhXDg1FFw5NTQ+MFxRMlxWNFxGOSlcQU5cUURcMDDRv1xHV1xRNFww
MBcQXDAwAwFcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDARIVw5MFxSMFxK
RlxPTFwwMAgBAVwwMAY/Alw4NFxDRxZXJVxUV1wwMFxKRlxONFwwMCIQXDAwAgICAgMBAQEBXDAw
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwARARIDEhMEBMT2JHZWBcV0pcRExcMDAIAQFcMDABPyHzm6KSXFE0
XDhaXEY5XDk1FTQ1XFJUXFYzXEgyJWtxXEwyXEJHXFQ4d1w4NVxXSlwwMAZcRk9/IVxMOFxaNlxG
M1xVUT5wXDg2XEpFM07ZsVxQQ3dcODF/F1JcUDhpXEk0XEIyx7F3S1xERi15XFM0XFZJHxxFGhbF
r1xQMj0PXE4wLgVcQTcmXEY3cnpRXEoybFxNMlw4NQsvLQVcTlo8XDlHXFIxelFcSjFcOUEhXEw4
XE5aNlw5OFxDOFw4UilSXFJJdVw4NlxPOFwtXFE4XFk0KFw5Qz0WH1xSNktcVjFPCnwqX9OQIVw5
QyZcODJcOE0sXnxDXDg4LFVcRTFMXDg1XDk2TXZcSTDRllo5I9OKGFxNOB5cUDBYXEcwYRxcUlQL
XEhGBVxRNFxPOXZcRldM3Ytz14FAXEhCYh3KlQdcUTJWXDg2aiFjTlxWSlxBOFxQNVxRRFwwMARc
QlIvXE82XFMybFxBMToUXE04VmHYl96lDlxEOSpcOFNcVDBcOVQTXEY5XEExYVxMMVxEQ1w5Ulw5
MVxRMCEqXjNIZlw4QlxRNSBcTzMaXEI3c1xTU1xWMVxKNVpQVVw5NFxDOWsuGVxTOH47KEY+XDg2
XFY4fwNrXDkycStcTk8hDFxCQjdcVlBlXEUwSl1bTWclKVxEMFxCNVxXMFxPMFxXSQZcOUFcODVc
TE7aqDh9XDg1IltcWjcPXEI1XFJQEkJcRTJcOUY6E1w4OGFcUVlcRjdcUjQ40rNlcFNnXEwxD25R
FlxDUlw5NFxTMEFcSDlofFxNUTBcWTNcRTVcVDNOXFY4XEUxHMSHXEFOSFw4Q1xHNQZ6RFxXR1xG
NDhcOTUoXEwzQnJcQjVlXFBSXEVCfSh7FlxON8OJb1xENHRcOFIfCHBcVjhsNVxBUU5cQjReXEdS
LciyzatcODVcUDVcOTZcUjZcSEFqXDhNXFo2Llw4RU5cODlcOFNcVTlcSDI5C1xGMX4PXEwxY1xB
NjVcRjJQUHfqhKlBQlxRMBZcTVlcQjE4MnwfXDgxXFZRSFxJRCtcODZ0XDgzXFEwLUFCXFcyYR5c
VjFiXEI2XEwxXE1BXEI5XFMxXE8zXDgzClxSM0VcQTkPXDkzc3scSwoXXEI3Zlw5NFxUOMWOXFIx
ZFw4RmdpSx5cODdcRDkIZMaixaDdqFxTN1xUNF9Wa1xETSsXDElcWTRcOUZUVlxVSRZcODdcQ0wd
IVw4NjwUPlxNNVw5M1w4N9CdXEMwLxBcQzBaXDlTXFMxVFxGTFxPNmpdXDgxblhcUTQxXFZJE1xD
N1xPUWhcRDlcVjBcUFIKXEc0MSlcQzNcUUwzeVxCUmkX4KGWXF5EXDlHNFxDNSlcTjNcTllcRjUg
XFRQcFxGMlxGTVxPMFxCRzNcVFBcVEhcRVAWL1xOMFhcOUdhXDk2XE84XFc1XEdBy4dcT0xJXDhF
XFMzXE9UWlw4NVxBMFxNNVw4N1xNOUh1FlBzXDk2UGlcOTZePBFcRU5cTEN6XFQwXE84Llw4NVxT
NVxHQlxPTRtSIVxGOFxTN2lCEzJcODRcRThmXE0wSi5cOTFBXDhHXFI5X2VWRlxCM0RcTUIfQ1w4
N1xVU1xUOVZcQU5cUEFES1xTMlxSRTVcOUIsXE0yXFEyR1w5NRVcOUIdXFMwe1w4UB8GXFcyZ1xG
MCVrXE0zUxRcOTlcRDFcVDhcUjd6IVxFQ0FcUTB7XDg1O1w4QwhDaNaQXFI4T1xGNFxGTxpcUEJc
OEVcVjhcUFZKXEU1XE1OKwUULVxDR1xTOSx6XFIxXEVCH1xOMFxRM2dVexBcVjJcUzNZXEZCE0Us
XE8yXEI3XEQxShspXE9ULF4gF0d0N3JcTDhXXEczX1w4NtGNXFdSCtesXFRGZVw5NkpwXDlBXDg1
QlxXNCVcTzkcTlw4SEtcUDFcUTlZXEQ3SFxPMFxVMNOxXEZBXDkxW1xOMVxMWlxEOSt8FFxWUlxW
SlxDTEk9XDk0TlxGMVxSMVhTXEk0PcKZT1xRTVxEMlxGVE1cVTN+XDhFfwZcODVcQVBKXERGJ1w5
VX5cTzJcUkplL1w4N1xQMCRrKxR/XFkxXEI4XFdRXFQ2exBcOTRcRkZcUDk/XFFEXEVSXDAwDAMB
XDAwAlwwMANcMDBcMDBcMDAQXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwBFwwMEBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDACVwFcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAEA2tcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAINDwIXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
AjNcSkJcOTBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAgAkRcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDACXDAwBWNcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcOTN7CFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFw5
MEYkXDAwAQRcQzA4XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAgFcMDBcMDBSJBAbAlxSMlwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFwwMAEgAiAEElogN1xGOARcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcOTIgA1xFMScgEkxcOU4K
XEEwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwIFwwMFw4MkhcVlLQnQpcV0hcOTRcODBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
OTJBIj4BJ2lcUDVcQzdcRTQ6IFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAgkckBcMDACQFwwMA5cVFVcRjJcOTRcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcOTBHXDg4XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwGVxNNTtcMDBcODBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAg
YVwwMFwwMFw4MFwwMFwwMFwwMAHOoCBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAQWUxcMDBcMDAGTkRcMDBcMDBqXEYz
XDgwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwIBEQXDAwFFxGMFwwMFxPT1wwMFwwMAFcRDNFXDgwXDAwXDAwXDAwCFxV
NFwwMFwwMFwwMElcVkhYXDgwXDAwHFxNNFxPMVwwMFwwMFwwMCRcMDBcOTJcMDBcMDBiXDAwXDAw
DlwwMFwwMFwwMFw5MVw4MlwwMFwwMFwwMEAoXEQwCFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAJcODNA
XDAwXDAwBFw5MjJcVDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDACXFMxXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAlxU
OAhcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAGXEc4AlwwMFwwMFw5MDpYXDkyXDAwIFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFwwMAItJFwwMFwwMFwwMNKpIFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAEEXDAwXDAwA1xRMFw4MVwwMFww
MFwwMFxRNRJAXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAghcMDBcMDAEXEFDAkAEXDk4XFM4SFwwMFwwMCRcMDBcMDAE
XDgwXDAwBC5cUkkEXDgwIAtJXE00XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwDlw5NFxNOFxaM1xHMSBc
MDAnXFI5XDAwYFxQNVwwMBBcMDACXdy/XFI5cmJTXDAwSVxBNSgDXDgzRQ5zXFA4TFxGRVw5N1xP
MlxPMSwQAVw5MnhcRTAlX1xWNlxSMzkkSnQtXDlDXEwxGCBcODJlD1w5Mlh4XFRSXFY3XEozQjRc
UTFCDj5cOVkBBWFcUzPEpEJcOVNTdlw5T2pcQUVtZlPIgkU2XEZPZVxCOOW2ni1cW1w5RXpcUDNc
VEg4IBFcRTfemzgaeFxMNFtcWUMoXDlVXFI5NRdcUjYBXDAwfFw4N1w5SVxEN3dcOU3MvVw5MDbQ
jGVbXEUwXDAwQA5cUjVcUzdcOVYFXEk5Ds+g0ZJcQTDUvhlcMDAQDlxMOFxMQjxcRVZhXFZINlxE
T1xPRHlcVjVZXFYzXDkwXDAwBFwwMAVLClw4RFw5TVxOMVxZMVxHNVxXU1xTNlxIQ1xPTnZcMDBc
MDBcMDADSlw4NVxSOFxPOC1cUzkvGk9hXDk3woJcMDBcMDBcMDBTXEwxfFgHRFxSUlxXN389XEY0
XEZOOVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMBAgXDhMXFo2XEUwA1NcUlXck1w5Slw4RFxOMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMARc
MDACXFFEXDAwXEdWXDg5bzfChtiIdVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMCBcODBcRzlJXDhNA3si34hcOFBA
XDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAQRcOTBcMDAEKlxBOdCUXDg5XEY0XDgwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAw
AQQCcj8eQExcVEUIXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAVwwMAp5XDhOXDAwfCRcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBMXEMwXDkySiAWWVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFww
MFwwMFwwMFw4MkAkXDgwTyBcODBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDBc
MDBcMDBcMDBcMDBcMDAPXFdKXEM0XDAwIxEBXDAwAgICAwEBAQEBAVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAFcMDAR
EDEgITBATEJOcnJgZFxXSlxETFwwMAgBAwEBPxBcUURcMDBcRDdcVTNcVFRcRjBcQk4vXFEyXDg4
XEMxP1w5NG98XFRQXFdHXEEyJFxMOFw5T1xER1wwMCgxaF9cVDJWXEYxZVxQMVxRQ09cU09cVjBc
SkZcMDAgXE9RClw5Wn8gXEQ1QVw4UFxWSFxBOHoVclxEOVw5R1xWNh9cUDgIN1xVSgpcRTEYXFFN
CFw4WXlKKVw5NVw5VFxXMgtcSUMDXDkwXE05XEwyX1xaNANcQjIpXFVTBlxUMFxKRFw4MXxcUDNO
ElxBN1xHMRE3XDgxXDkwDlxSMdGSMD1GXFU2XEkyXEJPbBgTXEE5XEc4VVxPVcOoHFw4RzFcRjRc
TzQLbSgLXFk4BlxHVFxTODtcOFJFXEE5fkc+XDlMXDgxakYRQFxVM1xSMlxXRVw5OFxCM2JiVVxG
OdyBZEAKPAN2XDg0XFJKEFw4OFw5QlxRMH1cODg1KGBcODNcUERcQjNcVzExR1w5MC9VP3QGXDhF
Vk81zql6XEY1XFc1IEtcVjgtF1w4SlxBNz1hXDk0X8i3XE85XERHXDAweQQPXFI4I1xSR2xcUTJW
KiU1PhBcQTZcRVZpXFVIQFxCNlxMMEhcXEIzSVxTN0NcUjAfXEYwaitcUFEbd1w4MlRZflxUU01N
UlxRMw5cRERcVTUW24JcOE9cVzZcODd1VhtqWtipWXBcUzZ6XDgzXFNGXDg0fFw4MXNPXE00a1xG
VVxQVVxHM0Q8XE1PCBc1TVxDV2RhARBcRzNPXDkyXFEyZVw5MFNcOEdcUzlcTzQxXFVKXEM2TE9c
QzhFHVxUT0I9XDkxMlw4MQpHCFxBN1w4OFw5T1w5OBU1XDlPIVw5NCwLXFlHTVw5OCdcUjlmXEpE
XDk1XW1cTDFcOVpcODR3bwgtXDgxR1k7GFxJNFxDMg9cTjhcTjE/JVxZMlxEVgFuXFY2JzZcODIs
FFxGOVxCTRlcTTQ4XENEXFcwEEVcVkUXXEY3B0JlXDkwXEMxU1xVOCFkXFU1E1xFOUdcUDRcTERc
RDRcMDDUtmwQYH5cUzZcUkZcQ1FcUTMVXDk3XEEy3YxcR1XDj9CIXDlQXFY2RVxBNuW6ly5cTTRh
RTtcQzIzXFY2XiRuXDgyXFVFXEUwXEwzXFBEB0UYdlxRMl9DXEZEXE44XE4xXENCXFwwMFxSOB5c
VFQ52Y11XDlGOFw5MVxOMRwOXFBEXDgyXEUxNWBcODRcUjl8XFA1XFY0YEI6XDhDXEwzcVxDMVxC
OFxWN2o0WFw5MRwYBwJcSUMxClw5NUtcTjBwfdeAXDlCXFQxXFAyJVUjDCVcOTVcODNcRTdcODlc
ODNcODZcQzhrVVw5NVw4NFw4MAJcWTZcQzByXFNVVF9gXERQd1xDR1w5OFxUMw9cT1RZR1xNOUJc
QTBcQjUwXFZRaGLshoRcQk5cUUMyXEcxXFJQB+S6gx1cVzAsZlNcTk5pKybmsJhtVRhcTzFcOFZe
FRFcRjZFXFE1OkY3XEMwXEdVbCVcVEVhZFxNN1w4MGgOCzU3DlxDMVxSMmIrdRhcRThcRTBcTDlD
XFk1YFxDNSsLYHJcUlIGXEVFLFxQOCVcUDFcQkRQXg9cODRxCsqdRMWLdlxGMFxNMFxOMwMMDBYo
XEJGN1w4MURZClw4MTJcOTBNL1w4MlxKMVw5RFw5OX1HKyVcTTBgblxEMm4uRSFcVDBcODd8QVw4
MlxGOQZcTDPesVxNQVxDOWlcUjljLFw5NSoYXEo5LlxBMB3HqFxNN1xQMFw5OBsuLlVcRFVpLgoz
Z1xJNXlKXE9aK1w4My4YCjBcRlcGSlxTSCpcOUVcUDJpdNSkXEJXXFFUXEg3A23Llx4XNlxRNFxP
NgJcQ0ZOXFM2ZV5LXEQ464qxXE04ZURcRlYPJ1xSNRTUv1xVOVNcQ05fXFE0XDg5Qz0TeVN0XFY1
XEdEXE4wXEw4PyJwX3fiobl3XE81XFNIXDk4XEFRD1xPNGZcOEdcVjYKNy5cUzNcVDF9XEkxXERP
XE40XERCVVxQOFxSOSkYXEY1XDgyXDlDXDk0XDgzYiLUv3wFXEw3bVFfWVw4NkoqX1w4UlxJQht/
AlxPNV5WXERHXDAwXFYyf1xUV1xHNFwwMCMRAVwwMAIBBAMBAQEBAVwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMFwwMAFc
MDARECAhMDFAQUFCeXJgZ1xUV1xIQVwwMAgBAgEBPxBcUVFcMDBcOEREXFVUXFRHXEM5XE9OXEFH
e1xWNS0XH1xSNwQWXFc5XVw5M1xINlJcUFBcRDk9XEQ1Klw5NStcVjXKq1xRNVxUMFxINlxGUVww
MCVCUVxCVFxQV1w5MlxGMVxCTx1fXDkwXEw5VFw4Qlw4Mlw4V1w5MFxUMFxSOVVrXE1RLBcVXFk3
XEdSXDlUXFZFP1w4OFxBOFxMUVxBRXhcT1RcI1xGQ2c8XDgxMCZcOE0lXDlZHVxHU1w4OW5cOFIy
XEUwWxZcRjdwXFA4XENDXFYzK1xSVAFcSDYSRWtcOExyXEVTBw9cUjQRXFZGIGJcOFBcUDJcWjZc
RzJXE1xPM1xWMgVcRzE7XEMwXDkxWidcUFoGXEdSXDg5c1ZcR0NcTjJcTzQ0DwwVXFkyBCh4FVxW
UFw5VFdcQTl3TClcODhcREdcMDBcOTlcUzhhXFNKDC1cQTJcMDBcODARPCdcTDVcODglMlxQRFxH
Mi4dXFNUXDlWHUhaLipcTTdcTjFwXEcwXFNTH0oQTmNcTUxcQTEfXEJXB1xSOFxWMsa7XEg3clxR
NVxPOStFaUJcT1VcSkNcMDBcTTZcTTFcQzhcRTZcVjJcTzVBJU4lZFxPNDRcT0EbXEVWblxVMMOx
XEdFNlxNOFxNNFxbXEI3U1xTOChcUzB+XFIwXEU1MlxBOVxMN1xOMFwwMH9jXEc3PVxUNVxTU1xH
QRtcT1BOXEVUdU4tC1w5RlxBTVw5NQRH35RcRDZcODMFXEZTXDk1XFRSXDg2XEc5FR5bXERQRVIi
XEJWQAtzXDhVXEczd1w5TzxcTTJcXFkxXDhCF8e9AlxWMVxSVWtcQTdcOTgpd1xRQREEW1gfdVxQ
VFxHNFdecdCGHxFCalxGVlwwMEJcOTBVXEY3XEM5TBTOmGVjXEI5xLZcUjg3XDgwHUJcUzBKXEYw
REJcQjd+LVw5MVxDM1xVNAQbXFJVXEcwQVw4TFxRNllcODNcODFvEFtHKgpcTzdcUzQ7XEczFlxG
UFxOMUlcR1ZYXFQwOi5cRjVcQTBcOTVcOFFcTFlbXEdTXDg1XFBSXDlJXEI4MDRlXFAxXDg1HVxZ
MH1cRFJcUlJxUhhzC3UsaCwxbVxTNEdcOFNgXEU0Xgtgf1xBTzdcTDYGBlw4N3dcEVxDMwtcVjBc
UlIOXEgwXEQwZ1VcOUJ6Clw4VWA2XDg0LywMJXg7XDhWBlxIOGZcUE8jXFozHXlcV09YXElCUncE
C1w4MBJcREdcMDAnaVw5URhcVjlcRThtaRg2XE4wXEI0S2sdXDk4XFM5XFQ5LVxKNHtcQ09cUEEK
XDk3LgodcTtcODlhXDg0XFA4VmlcRTEvRFxON1xCMm9cODFcVDUYXFJSbAhFXDk2XE4xXDhQBlxa
QlxVMFxRM9qyXDk3KlxTMlxJQ1xOMN+LXEwxCmISXEI1EQxsBlxTM1w4M1RcRzBcOTJcOUFhXE0z
XFlFDDBcVlB6ZztcRjBcODJcUTU2GRZcTzRcQkNyO1xTMCQISlw5RVxEMlxRMFw4UFw5WVxEMXdc
UDRcU0gCXEE1VVw5NS0FGjsTZRdrXDk0NiPasnkeXDg0clxSVFJcOEFcUDJcTDlzBlxGMxBCXFEx
EFxSRRBcQjdcOTNExpZcTEFcQ1dMXFJHLy0qVlw5Myg3XDhQy4YFGyFcTTlwXEMz1ptcVjRPIidv
7ZuWXEcyXEYzShRtXEI2XEcxXFU2awJcUzVBLndcTDJcUTlcOTB7XDhZdgZcOTg2UlxTMHdcRzjb
h1xBTQJcTDNcODMGXDgxXDg3XEE2RNy1XFM0V1xVNwFcRjBgXDgwXERMMFVcODFcOVpcOUYHxazc
vQFcVlATDE0CXEg5QUk+JVxMODRcBVxEOFxEMWRHXFMyTzpcOTZcQjcUa1w4MmvCplxBOFxHVj4v
dlxSRlxCMiripKxvRwpz359TH1xUNiBzy5ZcVzhcSjZcRDV/XFAzXFFEXDAwXEdXXFE0XDAwJxAB
XDAwAgICAgICA1wwMAMBXDAwXDAwXDAwXDAwAVwwMBEhMRBSIFUwYUBiQVw4MVw5MWBcWTFcQzFc
VDFcVFdcSEFcMDAIAQFcMDABPxBcUU5cQzAQXEZUDE1cVjk+XEhBBnVKXFo1XEdUPjglJBhcVFVI
XDAwUEVcT0FcR1I4XFNVXEpDM1xMNTRcTVkgUlUPblw4M1ZgTlxCMFxPUW0IXERXXFQwXFVGXEUw
XE45AtCXf1kOXDhBXEdTXFMyXFJFQ1/Cm0IpE1kuXEQxNVw5NxdBXDk0XFU3EdCafwpcTzlTQwZc
OUIiPRBcTjMxHlxQMxsaXFk5XDgwXDlCXFNUXDg1XFM4XDk3YVxBUBgKclxaOFxDNwRcUzE0XFBV
R2JzXFFDEVxFNCUIXDAwBE1cVFJqUlw5NlwwMGJcTznsmJlcWUNcVzJ3K1xWSX1cOTNcRU5cOTVc
UTcpXENGX1w4UlxPN1xUOBJcSEFcUDhcUTBcQjNcRzRcOVImXE9XXEc1UFw5T1xMNCduXDhGXFYy
e1w4UGFcSTVcOUQzXFBMYHtcWjhcODZcRjF7XDhWXFNWehBHXDg3WXQpXFo3XDgz0I9IXFI5UFRf
XDg2XEUxOyBOXDk4XE1QXEFENtqBXFZRYDAXVVxFM9SpR1xMOFxMQ1xENF9PXDg5QFxSUhlcSDZc
QzE3AVxMMFxOQjN4XFc1FlxPMnNcOTlh369cRFEYXE4xXFlHXFQyEVxQOVcGLMahcVxETQFcTDFc
XEI5KRPGslw5RlxWNVw5U1xXOVxIOBFcQ01nQQpcQzJcUzcCXDhPXDk3THJdXEMxMlw4NghcUTB7
XDlNXFpHXFU4XFM4fghcUzUIXElFQzJcOTdcTVo+XEIwAVLChEtcVDIjXEY4e1xDMR1jUFxCM0kB
GVxTN1w4UQdcVkVoXDlMXE1DdlxSMhlnKcagXDk4374WXFIyXEVGFSpCXFA1QmITXDhXdFxSMFw4
SVxBM1xQTVxERVxUMFxPM1w4N1w4ODtcOFNcRTJXXFE0IVxNMn1cQUQHzLVcMDBcUzlcOFFgNGdc
SkFhElxNQWpcVjFSXFJJagtcTE5DG1w4OFxCVFw4U1xVNVxJNyYtFEUDXE9OdFxCU0ZcUjdcSUJc
UDcmXE5BX0tcMDBcUjNcODZcUlQHXDhISlxROGg7CChcQzJRXFdQXFYzcClcQjlcTTFcT1pcRDEL
XFZUXFY2OCxcODNcRThcRTF5eRhcRDBcRVQPXDk2XFRUXDlGXDk5H1xCOVw5MQVxOFw4MExqXEU3
FXooPlNcUjJBYSktXE03XDg1Yc+IX1w4M1xaOFw5MR5cRlZ+XFQ4P2wEeFxEUVxOMX5LXEQxXFI2
Fi4tXFAzXFIzBlw5N1xKRVxRMWY+SSBcRVZcUzhcVjFBAV4BfFwwMFxCNVxMOVxQOH9cWjNlXFc4
XDhPelw4MFxIRVRcUTUPXDlEagZcUjBcUVRcSDY9PVxGMFxMTFxaRxkgdyBRXFZJOCJcRE4OXFFB
AlxHOVxTUj1OGwx+4LeYDlw4NFxKQVw5UVxQNF9cWUJcOVZcUTdcV0Y2XDg3FlxBNe68nMuRZjVc
ODYSd8WMNVxEMFxCVRJcOTIMXlxPU1xFRRdeUTkBXDkyXFA2XDkwXEQ4M1xFV1xRMFxTMgZcOUZc
OUEceFxRQk5nXFI3XFQzYxtcRjQQKFw5N1xMT1xCNGchUlxTMg9cVDY1A3hcRjUFXE8wXE4zSlxH
U1w5NCxrXFcwFlw4OVw4OQZZblxPOUBPClxaRBFPXFRTXDg2XEZGKFxQMlxQNlxCMVxEMTZ9XFM4
XE9VXEo4LlxBM1xRTCcYCxZOXEVX5Y2oM2dQXEYzXEZNYlM8XEVVU1EhVQJcRTF6XE80WVRqYwNe
CgJcU0UmGkNcT1HCtFsMeGxcVVRcVDIoXDk5RlxBMFxOMWwVCFxZRFxXMlxRNj9cVEZcQzBcTTJc
TDJcQjEebFxWMUhUXEY3XDhCI1xRMG0OXEJCXFYyXDgyXFRSXEc3XEMwXFAwHlxQMFxaRVxWNghc
U1ZdHlxIMGlcTTgjMHpcQTVUXDk3Ylw4MwFcVFJcOTRcRjA/XEQ4b2kKXEQ4XDhEXDlUGj8BXFE1
XFdGXEUwf1xPTVxDMH9cRjkKXFcxXFIzXFZGXDgzIFxDOSlEDFxROFJcRjHftAgHaVw4NdaIXDhQ
XFU3XEg0XEM5eUNoClxHMVxTN1w4UlxUOHNkXEw2XDk1XE4yMVxCMVxHMFF/XDg4LnNcVEVPWiQC
XFExb1xCU1xPMxJcUjdcOTIqXEhDXFAyXEw0dDw0IVxCMTdfVUjauFw5NWJcRzVcRDRiF1xQQ25c
VzhcTzhkXEpGXDAwJlkIXExDXEI2XDg5XFIyYVw4M1w4V1xGMgpZXDg3XDgydFxQMVw5ODhcQTFc
Q1ZcUjlpxKtmXEExClgcLQxAJ9yI3Z9cTzRcREMgHT8aBlw5NkpcUjkT1axbXFIwJVxFRVxPOFIE
MlxCRFxUMFxTMGJcOUg8XEM1XFBRTlA6XFc4XFRXXDAwXEhFEUdKK3ZEDE1cXFM5w65DXDkyXEgx
EzBcRjZXXE9CTHEiXE8xR1dLXE4wTFxDREZcTzFcOTRcVzU/TFxCOVxMN1xQQhJcOUZaXE80NR8D
XDkxBzAdSxFcSDcOXDlBXE80SFxBMFxGMFxXMVxUV1wwMFxFQzYDSBtlXDk3MVJcRTJ6CmxcUzRc
ODZcSTd8XDlDXDgxw65dXFEyWVw5M0JaXDgzC1xWNVxSVAgoXEkyVFxRTVxDMVxFOFxWM2dcOFVc
OUpPDlxPMVxQWVxcQjFcOTdoXFI0NVxUSVxETnQKXEFGXFc5XFNXXDg3dFxFMVxPNwdeBlxMM1xa
MigtXDgwElxHVUFcVEVjXE5QXEFHGm9cUDlcOTVEUFw5N1xEOFxQMFw5NWVcXEFFxqVkT1w4NycH
R9+DXEczClxGMFxQTGceO1xGMFxVNE1cOFNwXEFMXE80XEFEHhpcVjNZXFYyXEgycCxcOVFcTDVg
XEIzZcqGXDk5XFJRXFIzady5ESoUXDgzXDk4XEYweWgYbVxEMVxVNw5cTzFcU0kdTSYSXE0wC1xO
MlooXEMzXAMKQ1w5NFgTJE1LXFVcOFArXEw0NVxBN1xGVlxPMiNDXEUyXEM3VzVeXE1CXEcwEVxT
U1xXOFxFQSFUXDkxBxw8O1w5T3YaXDhGXFM5aTRcOTd9JVxXMBoFXDk1XElFSANcTzRYXDgzZRUg
XVxVUVxWSlxFMDZVGnNcQzZcR1dcMDB1GylcVTRT04kaXEJMXE40XEJEXFU3XFNWYQZcQTE6TBJ4
CkFcOTNcOEZcVzhEMzA1w7hcOFZcRkFcODVcMDATdwXUpFxPOQJ5XEYxB2lcUFZLXEZPyatcTjJc
Q0d1UnpcOUpOXEw1AVxPOVxCNFxEOVxUT2FcSUITYVxONHpSC2BcODl4fA4fXFJScVxCOVxRTUtc
QzcRXFZTLVxTMzMmXEo4GVxGTWBcT0RcRjkLXFI2CjBTXDhWElxHNW4+XE1OXEQ0SzQ8ZSlcUFY2
L1xJQlxRNzZcTDYbeVxGUgp4XFIyI1V9RUpcTzRcQ0YsJ2hcVFJcODFcODdcODcQLFw5SlxCNFxM
NFxQMUVcQzVVYgZoBlxIOWJ5XExZXEI1XDgzO1w4U2MgXFc1Ch5HXEJQKxXevFw5MsmSNFxRMHFf
XEZWClw5UTVcVTJYI1xGN1w5NlxRNxcrXDkxXE41blxGNzwzLkxcU1NsZmNxElw4N29cQjYxM1w5
OVg6fFFcODYDXFJJXEUxEFxPMVxQNkpHclxTMyYyaFxFRlxRNy5cTDVcWjJcRVZcUzVcV0hcQ01c
UTZIMQdSOVxVOVxRMkgpRDMIW1xCONC2Nlw5ODhcXFExXE1aXDg3KiXZm1w4MiBcQlYWAVxQVisD
XEpCXDk0XDkzfVxNUSAMbCJcQjdcOFZcODNDXFdIRFxOMHkwXFkzXEM4PFw5VFxSVyAmQ1M9XE0w
XEwwXFo2PlxDV1xSMQJlA3pcQjFyXDg1XE01XEMzZVxSNRfXhlxPVVxHNS9OXFA1c3xifVxENDJQ
XFNXXDgxGnUHQA7Io0lXXE003LFcQzRcRzAFXDk3aVxTN1xXSlwwMHlQYBJcODZcODhcTTRBLFxC
OFw5N1xUMgxcT1c1NFw5Rmp7XE0xXFEyXFkwXEZWclw4VDNcRUJcTTNcODE0XDkxXE1aXERzWFpz
XEE5Y1xQMVw5QwEFXEMzZ1xSVDRcOEoRZeGMrENcUDY7IBhcOTlcOENcRFcuXE81W1xWSRg/Ayph
XDhRXFA0XEMxB2VOXE84XDhWXDk4XEpCDiFnXE43alxFOVxVUW5cRzBcRTZcUDBcTzR1ElUDXDk4
XFZTAnVOXDlCLUJcUDJtXDhDXDlTXFNTXEowXDkwdllcTVlcOThuXFJTY1w5NEhcRDlcUDI7XDlN
CFw4MVxZQ1xUUSlcUzlTclw5MVxRNFw5NkdcWjAgWkgpXE82D1w4MF8KOxhzPxlxXDg4XEI0PlxM
OFJWRFwgbTF+XFRXXDAwdSkpH0IkXFFMXDgzZSEgTlJcVDcMXFRFXEY3XE4yEC1gZw9cQTl2MThc
U1BZGlxHQ1pcTTlnWA9tBVxSNcq0Z1xHMVw4QxtcOUwdPhZcOU4pXDgyXDhEbQ9OXFNVXEo5ecOO
XFBRXDg0TFxDOTUTG1xWT1xVSlxFNFIlElw4MFZcOFlcRTkRGm4ZVQ5hZVxCOFwwMEFIXEM2JVxE
UxdcOFFcVDlZAVxEUHdbei8aAVwwMGklHlxTUTImI0sMGVw4N1xGNuiVolxCUVxQNFw5RFxHV1xS
OQo=
```

I put it in another code tag since it's also very big.

I told him I didn't have hours to spend on silly puzzles. So he then gave me a short hint:

> Boy, when you're with me you're sure stumped!
>   Don't worry, when you get it you'll pop your confetti to celebrate.
>   basethenvinotvithenbase

He said all 4 are related to a song that relates to him in a few days.

**What song is it, and how does it relate to him?** (Reasoning for the clues are optional but recommended.)

Comment: If the answer is "My Name is Jonas", I'm going to be disappointed that I didn't have to do any actual solving in order to figure it out.

Comment: This is very broad

Comment: @IanMacDonald No, it's not. :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Should I add another clue?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I think you need to narrow it down, maybe add another tag which gives a hint. Its also a bit long

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's long due to the size of the clues. I'll add a more concise hint and find some better tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> The song is Birthday, by Katy Perry and Jonas' birthday is coming up, soon.

The first part is a vigenere with

> Yo

as the key.

It translates to:

> sO MakE (s0 maKe) A W1sH (a wIsH

Will noted that these are lyrics from

> A Katy Perry song.

question_asker looked it up and found that it's from

> The song Birthday.  This song is on the album Prism, as noticed by the image from the second code.

The second part decodes, from Base64, into:

```
ÿØÿàJFIFGGÿþ^What could it be?
Who knows?
But, dear puzzlers,
I'll give you a taste
of your own medicine.ÿÛC"9%""F25)9RHWUQHPN[fƒo[a|bNPr›s|‡‹’”’Xm ¬ŸŽªƒ’ÿÛC""C%%C^P^ÿÂ#rÿÄÿÄÿÚ ú9Ð
@$  ÄÊJØCQ/§x‰[8ÎjÙ9UlN3Íôo¤U‚ô’ EP±/F—9Mz7Œæ„´ÎkKB^³‚PÖÌs­µ™PàŽ  C‰(ÿÄA 01B!ÿÚáø!¨qˆÀ£,¡½t1‹,Ìy1;û¢N<ðÙ{¿ÿÄ0@PÿÚ?ªUåßÿÄ0PÿÚ?©3OÿÄ`ÿÚ?ÿÄ1! AQÿÚ?!G$ZrH|  løO|0-¢–YTaê=ùá³B ®`{æ(Ý DØLºÄìh¹\·[d6btÇê?ÿÚ  l½îfÎÞ¢’tDyz3aé+­ô£XˆM¹ÿÿÄA1! ÿÚ?Ù¦VÅFÄÆÄó¸ý¸ýÇàƒ&\é÷§Ñ RA;Þçƒ…)> :Rlü"  Y3ÿÄ!A1 ÿÚ?0j-BÑ­)!Ð´hJÇBðä!±„^žÉÁ±6!–'gF¶9žG¢¥  ±XWÝŒ²þ¿ÿÄ !1AQqa¡ÁÿÚ?k:÷Žtëâ~8Ï7P=áûû½‡ŸÄX6Ho!zl[ÜË«o–öàéñyã(y,_V—5’ëmŒ{³ç Qß2Ë»ú—ë(âc!‰á†7moâÛYeœÞÀžXÏq çf<(c>âÆWäÌ€Ìôá’wf¯cÂbfÐ{=}<Må­ÿÙ
```

As noted by Will, you can view it, as an image as:

> [image]

The third part has a separately encrypted section in it.  @question_asker was able to decode it out to

> THIS IS MORE CLOSELY RELATED TO YOUR DEAR ORIGINAL POSTER THAN YOU THINK LOOKING FOR THIS IMAGE‌​ WILL NOT HELP YOU BUT MAYBE THERE'S ONE THAT CAN IT'S BEEN IN FRONT OF YOU THIS WHOLE TIME AND YOU'VE STI‌​LL MISSED IT
>     Again, this one is from a vigenere cipher using ERNYYLOEB as the key.  (Rot13 from REALLYBRO)

Comment: Sorry, no luck getting the spoiler codes to work with this.  It was even worse if I added the decode from the third puzzle.  http://pastebin.com/XhpkK9ya

Comment: You can use <pre> tags inside spoilers

Comment: I did - it didn't help, any

Comment: Oy, I'll concede - that's a mess!

Comment: Thank you for trying.  I'm still new to the site, so was hoping I missed something.

Comment: This is correct, although the third hint's reasoning is off. I'll accept this and post the correct reasoning for the third hint as a separate answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I will, since I may be able to use the same trick in another puzzle. (The answer is still correct, though.)

Answer (score 3):

## Partial answer

The part Khale_Kitha mentions yields this image when viewed in a browser

> [image]

Comment: stupid question time: what do you mean by "when viewed in a browser"?

Comment: Either saved as a JPEG and opened in a photo or web browser, OR entering `data:image/jpeg;base64,[CODE]` in your URL bar.

Comment: aha! I didn't know about the data:image trick, thank you